# Can't ping device through hostname (and avahi installed) from pc

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot

I need to ping and establish communication with an embedded device through its hostname. I'm using the latest buildroot and I enabled avahi and mDNS. 
The first problem is that my hostname at startup is always `buildroot` and the problem is how change my hostname through avahi library and apply immediately on the network.
Can someone help me to configure my device?

Comment: Do you mean this https://linux.die.net/man/1/avahi-set-host-name ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use `hostname newname` and that command but I don't get any results...

Comment: avahi-set-host-name and hostname are two different commands.

Comment: ok, but what should I use?

Comment: Any progress? I have same issue. My rpi0w connected to my wifi network and I can see it but without hostname, only realize new device connected and I say "hello little fellow you arrived yet" and see like 192.168.1.10 then I can connect **ssh root@192.168.1.10**

But, when I use raspberry os, I always can see the hostname of rpi when search my network (you know, raspberrypi.local)

It is bad, because when I use more than one RPI I could not recognize which is which, then try more than one time.